# Geolocator.getServiceStatusStream() is not defined?

Tags: flutter, geolocation

I'm using the `Geolocator` version `7.0.3` flutter package in my project and wanted to listen for the service status changes. In the documentation they are stating:

> To listen for service status changes you can call the getServiceStatusStream. This will return a Stream which can be listened to, to receive location service status updates.

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

StreamSubscription<ServiceStatus> serviceStatusStream = Geolocator.getServiceStatusStream().listen(
    (ServiceStatus status) {
        print(status);
    });
```

**But** when calling `Geolocator.getServiceStatusStream();` this error is shown:

> The method 'getServiceStatusStream' isn't defined for the type 'Geolocator'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getServiceStatusStream'.

Even in the [breaking changes in 7.0.0](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/wiki/Breaking-changes-in-7.0.0)

there is nothing saying that they moved it somewhere else or removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use version `7.1.0` or higher